Why can't std::enable_if be applicable to operator overloads as an additional function argument?
As per cppreference documentation, which says  (emphasis mine):

std::enable_if can be used in many forms, including:

as an additional function argument (not applicable to operator overloads),

as a return type (not applicable to constructors and
destructors),

as a class template or function template parameter.



Why can't it be applicable to operator overloads when using enable_if as an additional function argument?

Because operator overloads can't have additional parameters, right?

It is mostly correct, but there are some exceptional operator overloads like operator() - see my answer below.

@wohlstad This is not operator overload, this is function call operator.

@273K I am not a language lawyer, but operator() appears in the documentation for operator overloading - see here.

Most operator overloads have a predefined signature.
Some examples (for class T):
// copy assignment
T& operator=(const T& other)

// prefix decrement
T& operator--()

// postfix decrement
T operator--(int)

(You can see the full list here).
Which is why you cannot usually have an additional parameter for enable_if.
It is a bit similar to the reason enable_if is not applicable as a return type for constructors and destructors (the 2nd bullet in your quote) - they simply don't have any.

However - it is worth noting that some operators listed in link above (here), do not have a predefined signature, and can actually be used with enable_if. One of these is the call operator (operator()).
An example with the call operator limited to integral values is shown below.
In that sense I think the cppreference quote is not 100% accurate.
Example:
#include <type_traits>

struct X
{
    template <typename T>
    double operator()(T a, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type* = 0)
    {
        return static_cast<double>(a);
    }
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    x(3);      // Compiles OK
    x(3.f);    // Does not compile
}

Live demo

[over.oper.general]/10:

An operator function cannot have default arguments, except where explicitly stated below. Operator functions cannot have more or fewer parameters than the number required for the corresponding operator, as described in the rest of [over.oper].

